# Is LocationListener in android works like loop?

Tags: android, gps, location

I used `LocationListener` to calculate the speed of the moving mobile. I used `location.getSpeed()` to get the speed. My task is if the device speed crosses exceeds already set speed limit it send an SMS as `ALERT- OVER SPEED` to some other mobile number. I used a `Flag Variable` `boolean flag;` to check conditions. My problem is if the mobile travel above the limited speed for 10 seconds continuously it has to send only one message. But my App sends message as long as the device goes above the speed. I set flag variable but no use. My code is

```
 private void sendOverSpeedAlert() {
    Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,"Over Speed Alert Set",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final SharedPreferences account=getSharedPreferences("admins",MODE_PRIVATE);

    String overSpeed=account.getString("osa", "");
    double overSpeedKm=Double.parseDouble(overSpeed);
    final DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
    String overSpeedFormat=dFormat.format(overSpeedKm);
    final double overSpeedDouble=Double.parseDouble(overSpeedFormat);

    final LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            final double currentSpeed=(location.getSpeed())*3.6;
            String currentSpeedString =dFormat.format(currentSpeed);
            final double currentSpeedDouble=Double.parseDouble(currentSpeedString);

            if ((currentSpeedDouble>=overSpeedDouble)&&(flag==false)){

                CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude=location.getLongitude();
                        DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.####");
                        Date date=new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
                        String time=sdf.format(date);

                        SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                        String sms="'ALERT- OVER SPEED'\n\n'!+"+decimalFormat.format(latitude)+",+"+decimalFormat.format(longitude)+","+time+"'\n\nSpeed= '"+currentSpeedDouble+"'Km/Hr('"+overSpeedDouble+"')";
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(logPreferences.getString("admin1", ""), null, sms, null, null);
                        flag=true;
                    }
                }.start();
            }

             if (currentSpeedDouble<20){

                flag=false;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

It will be called anytime your device changes location. You set falg, but you change its value when you send your message, 10 sec after cross the limit of speed. You should change that right after detecting it.